# Getting Actionmailer to send an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have asked a question similar to this and received some great help, it has clarified some understanding and concepts.This is the first time using actionmailer so I am trying to get a better understanding

What i am trying to achieve is for an email to be to sent to a user who clicks a remind me button. It is a simple library app where a user can check out, check in and request a reminder when a book is checked back in..I’m just struggling on this last part of logic, once I see it working Im sure I will understand it better

So when the check_out status changes for a book there are various posts to the book model

```
Check out

<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :checked_out, "Check Book Out?" %>
<%= f.check_box :checked_out, {}, true %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :checked_out, :value => true %>
<%= f.submit 'Checkout' %>
<% end %>

Check In

<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :checked_out, "Check Book Back In" %>
<%= f.check_box :checked_out, {checked: false}, false  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => nil %>
<%= f.hidden_field :checked_out, :value => false %>
<%= f.submit 'Check In' %>
<% end %>

Register Interest

<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :remind_me, "let Me know when book back in" %>
<%= f.check_box :remind_me, {checked: false}, false  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :remind_me, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit 'Remind Me' %>
<% end %>
```

In my book model I have this logic to recognise that when a book is checked back in after a remind me request has been made an email is sent notifying the user that the book is back in the library

```
after_save :reminder_mailer

def reminder_mailer
if !self.checked_out && self.changes[:user_id] && self.user.nil?
ReminderMailer.remind_email(@user).deliver
end
```

and my action mailer

```
class ReminderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "my email address"

def remind_email(user)
@user = user
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Library Clerk")

end
end
```

As you can probably see I am struggling with what to pass as the users email who made the remind me request. When the remind me request is made I post the users_id to the column remind_me. I have a seperate user model (devise)..

Is part of my problem being that when the users_id is posted to the remind me column it is then just a regular integer and not linked to the users_id?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Reminder` model (and table in DB) that keeps track of reminders that users have set

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reminders
end
```

Show a button beside a book, make sure to add `@reminder = Reminder.new` to the action that renders the following form.

```
<%= form_for @reminder do |f| %>
<%= f.label :remind_me, "let Me know when book back in" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :book_id, :value => @book.id %>
<%= f.submit 'Remind Me' %>
<% end %>
```

You will have a reminders controller, (add `resources :reminders, only: [:create]` to routes.rb)

```
class RemindersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:reminder][:book_id])
    Reminder.create(user: current_user, book_id: @book.id)
    redirect_to @book
  end
end
```

Then in the `after_save` of your book model, you would send emails to all users that have reminders for this book

```
def reminder_mailer
  if !self.checked_out && self.changes[:user_id] && self.user.nil?
    # get all users waiting for a remind on this book
    @users = self.reminders.map(&:user)
    @users.each do |user|
      ReminderMailer.remind_email(user).deliver
    end
    # remove reminders as users have been reminded
    self.reminders.destroy_all
  end
end
```

**Notice:** Make sure that you add a validation that no user will request reminder to the same book.

Comment: I was thinking of having a separate model, that’s what ill do then. Just for my own confirmation the id that sits in remind_me column was never going to access the user_id was it?

Comment: You don't need a `remind_me` column in `Book` model anymore, as said you will instead create a `Reminder` entry in db for every reminder.
You just need to send the id of the book and then use the `current_user` in your controller action.

Comment: also would you mind explaining Reminder.create(user: current_user, book: @book), i would have a reminder controller? and it would be in the create action? apologies unsure what you mean there

Comment: seem to get error Couldn't find Book with id= when clicking remind me, its passing a blank value in the params? sorry to ask again

Comment: make sure the form is rendered with the correct book id as a hidden field, and then check the server logs to see what it the name of the parameter that contains the book id.

Comment: got it passing the book id now, @book.id so thats all great..only thing now check_in is giving error undefined method `index' for #<User:0x46609c8>

app/models/book.rb:14:in `block in reminder_mailer'
app/models/book.rb:13:in `each'
app/models/book.rb:13:in `reminder_mailer'
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:18:in `update'

Comment: so at present i cant check a book back in, which is strange? any ideas on where i can look to resolve

Comment: all sorted, i was using mail(:to user when it should have been user.email  thanks for your help by the way, much appreciated, your answer has given me some insight into more ruby methods, ie the map, didnt know i could use that in this situation

Comment: you are welcome I updated your question to use `user.email` so not to confuse readers.